# How to use different mail interfaces (Mail System)?

Tags: emails

I have a newsletter (simplenews) being used from time to time and it uses SMTP server to send mail. 
All other emails from my site should be sent using default interface. How do I do this?

I thought Mail System module could help me with this, but seems I'm doing that wrong thus I can only **switch** between interfaces, but not **assign SMTP to simplenews only** and left other using default one. How can I do that?

Comment: At least for D8 the https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer module let's you choose different handlers for different modules.

Comment: I'm now trying to use Mail System module for that, but it ignores any custom settings I have added. It still changes default mail class, but when i'm adding a new setting for any module, it is being ignored and mail sent by the class set in default field. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For D7 you can define a custom mail system using the `$conf['mail_system']`

```
$conf['mail_system'] = array('mycustom_module_thekey' => 'MyCustomEmailSystem');
```

Then you can use the `drupal_mail` function

```
drupal_mail('mycustom_module', 'thekey', $email, language_default(), $params, $from);
```